# Parse.com using javascript not crawlable

Tags: parse-platform, adsense, googlebot, google-crawlers

I have a website and the content of it comes mainly from our Parse backend. I am populating content of the page after receiving a response from Parse.

I submitted a request to Google Adsense in order to be accepted in the program but I got "Insufficient content" as a feedback.
From the Google Search Console I tried to let it crawl our website but it seems that Parse contents are not crawled at all.

For that reason I thought that AdSense rejected our request.
Now the question is how can I have Parse content crawled and indexed? I found also this document from Google https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/learn-more which I think it is exactly the case but I don't know how to apply it to my situation.

Does anyone had this issue already? And how would you solve it?

Thank you in advance for your feedbacks which will be highly appreciated.